# event listener 'change' is not engaging?

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I'm trying to read in a file, split the words out into an array, count the length of each word, then reassign each word into a new array if the word is greater than a number entered.  When the file is selected, thats when the function should execute, perform the above logic and display the result to an element.  The EventListener doesn't seem to be getting triggered when I set a breakpoint in Chrome.  Any suggestions?

I've included the JS and html for troubleshooting.  Thanks in advance!

```js
function filteredWords() {

    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput'); //create a variable for the html input 
    var displayResult = document.getElementById('displayResult'); //create a variable for the html display
    var temp = document.getElementById('num').value;
    var num = parseInt(temp, 10);

    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        
 var file = fileInput.files[0]; //store the first file into a variable

        var textType = /text.*/; //create a variable for checking if file type is text

        if (file.type.match(textType)) { //if the file is of type text
            var reader = new FileReader(); //create a new file reader object
            var text = "";
            var wordArray = [];

            var filteredArray = [];

            reader.readAsText(file); // read the file

            reader.onload = function (e) { //for the onload event

                text = reader.result; //assign result to new variable

                wordArray = text.split(' '); //split the text words into an array

                

  for (i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) { //loop through the array and replace largest word with largest in array
                    if (wordArray[i].length > num) {
                        filteredArray += wordArray[i];
                    }
                }
                displayResult.innerHTML = "Your filtered words are: ";  //display the result in the browser element
                for (i = 0; i < filteredArray.length; i++) {
                    displayResult.innerHTML = largestWord + ", ";
                }
            };
        } else { //display a message if file wasn't read
            displayResult.innerHTML = "File not supported!";
        }
    });
}
```

```html
//inputs
<input class="" type="number" id="num" />
<input type="file" onclick="filteredWords()"  id="fileInput" />

//display
<p id="displayResult" class="control-label"></p>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*it doesn't jump into the event listener*"? what is "it", why should it "jump", and from where?

Comment: edited question to clarify.

Comment: But `filteredWords()` is triggered as expected?

Comment: Its triggered when the input is clicked to select the file.